# Good iPad SplitViewController tutorial?

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller, xcode4.3

I'm new to iOS development and am trying to learn how to use the iPad's splitViewController.
I've seen a couple of tutorials online but they all start with the master-detail template.
Can someone suggest a tutorial or give me an example that makes a split-view application from scratch as I want to know how it works...

Thanks!

-Shredder

Comment: After trying to make a split view using Interface Builder, I thought the master-detail sample application was *much* clearer, and very close to doing it from scratch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISplitViewController in ipad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465505/uisplitviewcontroller-in-ipad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kindly have a look on this tutorial with example http://www.mindyourcode.com/ios/adding-interactive-splitview-for-ipad/

Comment: Have many vote for this answer, so I think it'll good tutorial. But If this website is available now? I click on this link but the browser tell:"Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.mindyourcode.com"

Comment: Yep. What @lee said. Website's dead

Comment: The answer should really be updated to point to a correct location. Otherwise this answer is worth nil.

Comment: @lee The link is broken, but here is a snapshot: https://web.archive.org/web/20131016234339/http://www.mindyourcode.com/ios/adding-interactive-splitview-for-ipad This site isn't pretty but it'll do the job :)

Comment: Web links to page that isn't live.

Comment: Guys original page is live wohooo!

Answer (score 11):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial

Great website for iOS tutorials and source code.

Comment: I actually have already looked over this but it doesn't work with storyboards...

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: For people googling this like I have, this tutorial linked has been updated to use storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

You guys might also want to check this out. It's done programmatically.

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2013/05/uisplitviewcontroller-landscape.html

and

http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2013/05/uisplitviewcontroller-portrait.html

Answer (score 1):

Best tutorial for me was http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/.

Clear explanations with lots of illustrations.

Answer (score 0):

The following link will bring you to a tutorial on using a UISplitViewController in an iPad app using Storyboards:

http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/iOS-5-How-To-Create-a-SplitViewController-iPad-Application