# How to arrange Tabbar on the left side of the screen

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, uitabbar

I am developing one iPad application using storyboard.For my application i need one tab bar on the left side of the screen.I do not want external liberies for tab bar.Is this possible to arrange the tab bar available in the story board arrange on the left side of the screen.

Comment: What's wrong with 3rd party libraries?

Comment: I am using cocoa pods and working as a part of team.I want to customise and add lot of functionalities to the tab bar.If i use external libraries it have some limitations.

Comment: The Apple iOS human interface guideline docs state that a tab bar must go at the bottom of the screen\

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned, use [**split view controller**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html) which will separate your iPad UI to **two parts**:

- Master view controller - This is usually a table view or collection view that display all elements.
- Detail view controller - This displays the detail of selected item in master view controller.

You can communicate between them with delegates, `NSNotificationCenter` or observers.

You can easily add separate `UITabBar` views to both **master** and **detail** view controller.

You can also read more about it on the links below:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial
- [Good iPad SplitViewController tutorial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986174/good-ipad-splitviewcontroller-tutorial)

Comment: I am supposed to achieve this functionality without using split view.So can you suggest an alternative for split view.

Comment: Do you have any particular reason for this? Otherwise just create two UIToolbars manually and you are done.